# meteor sync models to an JSON API instead of mongodb

Tags: javascript, meteor, sails.js

I'm writing an app where I'm planning on using meteor as my frontend and I already have my backend api written in sailsjs app.

Is there a way to break the dependency of saving models in meteor to mongodb? Can I do create/update/destroy models using an JSON api?

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert on Meteor.js but I am an addict.
I believe it can be achieved by using a Client only Meteor.Collection http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_collection 
Here are some similar questions on stackoverflow:
[Client-side-only reactivity with Meteor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929962/client-side-only-reactivity-with-meteor)
[How to sort a client-side-only (local) Meteor Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20443056/how-to-sort-a-client-side-only-local-meteor-collection)

and then using Meteor Methods: 
http://docs.meteor.com/#methods_header 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13145432/1147242

to do all the CRUD to your sailsjs API.

Here is a video from Eventedmind on Local Collections : https://eventedmind.com/classes/how-to/meteor-how-to-publish-to-a-client-only-collection
And on Meteor.Methods: https://eventedmind.com/feed/meteor-methods

Hopefully it will help.